# Hide excel's pivot table field headers

Tags: python, excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to work on pivot table in excel with python (using win32com.client). So far things worked fine but I've been not been able to hide the ***field headers*** from a given pivot table (like when you use the button in my screenshot).

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this whether in VBA or directly in python?

Comment: Use record macro, in excel, to determine the appropriate vba.  `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DisplayFieldCaptions = False`.  Also, the following project of mine, may be useful.  It's using win32.com for pivot tables in Excel. [Create Pivot Tables and a Regular Table with Python Automation of Excel](https://github.com/trenton3983/Excel_Automation_with_Python/tree/master/Pivot_Tables_and_Table)

Comment: Thanks. It worked :D. Also, I'm surely gonna take a look at your project.

Comment: The project is specific to my data,  but the Excel file of dummy data, is there in the project, so you can run it.